# Añadir una fila de un datagridview y seleccionarla en tiempo de ejecucion c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo una pequeña duda y espero me puedan ayudar a solucionarla.
El problema que tengo es que: necesito añadir en tiempo de ejecución una fila a un `datagridview` que lo realizo sin problema alguno, pero el detalle es lograr que se seleccione esa ultima fila que ingrese, ¿Cómo podría lograrlo?

```
  this.dataGridPre.Rows.Add(txtCodigo.Text, CodPac, txtPac.Text, CodOdontDos, lblOdont.Text, lblCedula.Text, cmbDent.Text,
                   cmbPieza.Text, cmbTratamiento.Text, txtValor.Text, txtPorDes.Text, txtDscto.Text, txtTotal.Text);
                    dataGridPre.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dataGridPre.RowCount - 1;
                    dataGridPre.Rows(dataGridPre.RowCount - 1).Selected = true;
```

Realizo este código pero me aparece error en **.Rows** que no se puede utilizar como método el miembro:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.Datagridview.Rows' no invocable.

¿Qué estoy realizando de manera errónea?.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use el siguiente código que cumple con lo que necesito hacer en el programa

> **dataGridPre.CurrentCell = dataGridPre.Rows[dataGridPre.Rows.Count -
>   1].Cells[0];**

Answer (score 0):

Si usa `dataGridPre.Rows(...)`, significa que intenta a llamar *Rows* como un metodo de DataGridView. Actualmente, *Rows* no es un metodo, pero un collecion de objetos.

Tiene que usar los parentesis cuadrados para selectar un Row unico, como asi:

```
dataGridPre.Rows[dataGridPre.RowCount - 1].Selected = true;
```